# Secretly recorded audio to meeting with landlord and now starting a dispute against him. Can I submit it as evidence?

Tags: privacy, rental-property, evidence, recording, british-columbia

My ex-landlord preferred to communicate by in person meetings. I began covertly recording our meetings with the microphone on my phone. Only the audio was recorded, not the video. My ex-landlord was unaware he was being recorded.

I am applying to the [residential tenancy branch](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/housing-tenancy/residential-tenancies/solving-problems/dispute-resolution) (RTB) with multiple concerns to get money from my ex-landlord. Can I submit the audio recording as evidence? I asked the RTB directly and they said they accept any type of evidence, however to check with the [Office of the Information and Privacy Commissioner](http://%20www.oipc.bc.ca). I contacted them but was given such a bureaucratic answer I couldn't make sense of it (I think it amounted to "we don't give legal advice").

Can I get in trouble for submitting an audio recording of meetings I had with my landlord even if he wasn't aware he was being recorded? On a couple instances other tenants momentarily joined in the meeting but walked away before it was done. Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can use it as evidence**

Canada clearly requires what is called a *one-party* consent for recordings. [Section 184(1)](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-46/section-184.html) of the criminal code makes it a crime to "knowingly intercept a private communication." However, Section 184(2)(a), the "*Saving Provision*," says the prohibition "**does not apply to**":

> (a) **a person who has the consent** to intercept...of the originator of the private communication or of the person intended by the originator thereof to receive it."

Because you: a) either originated the conversation or were the person your landlord intended to talk to; and b) gave your consent by making the recording; therefore, c) you are covered by this clause.

For more details, you can read nice summaries by lawyers [here](https://globalnews.ca/news/5114032/recording-phone-calls-canada-laws/) and [here](https://www.legalline.ca/legal-answers/is-it-legal-to-record-a-conversation-tape-a-call-or-bug-a-telephone/).